# how to stop jquery past the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using js to move my background photo from left to right and to move the header text right to left and down while scrolling. However, I'd like to stop the script once I'm past the header section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('#header').css("background-position",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*-0.65));
        $('#header').css("padding-bottom",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*.8));
        $('#headtext').css("padding-top",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*1));
        $('#headtext').css("padding-right",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*.5));
        $('#headtext').css("padding-left",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*-.5));
        if (parseInt($(this).scrollTop() > 10000) {
            return; 
        }
    })
</script>
```

I've been trying to add if or while statements to the above but every time I do, the js stops working. I have little knowledge of jquery so I'm not sure if the syntax is incorrect or if I need to approach this differently.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your header always the same height? I'm sure it's not 10000 pixels high though.

Comment: No. That was one of my attempts to see if any of the js would work if I had an if statement in there, it didn't.

Currently have CSS like:
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
#header {
 height:100%;
}

Comment: Not an answer but I don't think the parseInt is nessecary, the value of scrollTop() should already be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop()>jQuery('#foobar').position().top){
        /* something */
        console.log('stopped');
    } else {
        /* something else */
        console.log('resumed');
    } 
});
```

Where `#foobar` equals the element that will be used as a trigger, for the above code snippet, when it reaches the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function from jQuery to calculate if the header is still in view. Something like this:

```
if(($('#header').offset().top + $('#header').height()) < $(window).scrollTop()) {
  // Do something
}
```

Keep in mind that this snippet is seriously unoptimized code, so take the necessary steps to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses in your if statement. If you move it to the top of that block and flip your `>` to a `<` it will stop running the script once it gets to the 10000 or whatever you set as your header. here is your code updated

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if (parseInt($(this).scrollTop()) < 10000) {
            $('#header').css("background-position",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*-0.65));
            $('#header').css("padding-bottom",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*.8));
            $('#headtext').css("padding-top",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*1));
            $('#headtext').css("padding-right",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*.5));
            $('#headtext').css("padding-left",parseInt($(this).scrollTop()*-.5));

        }
    })
```